# How to group my results as nested array after join table with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

On my situation, i have two tables (collections, products) with having 1 to many relationship.

With code example, it is :

```
$collectionProducts = collections::join('products', 'products.collection_id', '=', 'collections.collection_id')->get();
```

My current result are :

```
[
  Collection 1 Product 1 => [
    ...Product Info
  ],
  Collection 1 Product 2 => [
    ...Product Info
  ],
  Collection 2 Product 1 => [
    ...Product Info
  ],
  Collection 2 Product 3 => [
    ...Product Info
  ],
]
```

And i would like to make the result like:

```
[
  Collection 1 => [
    Product 1 => [
        ...Product Info
    ],
    Product 2 => [
        ...Product Info
    ],
  ],
  Collection 2 => [
    Product 1 => [
        ...Product Info
    ],
    Product 3 => [
        ...Product Info
    ],
  ]
]
```

How can i achieve my expected results ? I know this is the common usage, i am sorry if there is any duplicated questions asked before, because i just cannot found any issues matched.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any reason you have not defined a `products` relation in the `collection` model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i don't know i can do it in model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something Laravel and its Eloquent relationships are really good at making easy for us without needing cumbersome joins.

On your **Collection** model create the relationship to products:

```
 public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Product");
}
```

Then when drawing your collections, you can include the products in an eager load for one simple call to the database:

```
$collections = Collection::with('products')->get();
```

And you have the collection you asked for.  You can pull all products from the `$collection` in a loop or whatever you like from here.

Example in a blade view:

```
 @foreach($collections as $collection)
     @foreach($collection->products as $product) 

            {{ $product->name }} //etc
```